# Pattern - Android

Tags: android, string

I´m using this code below to read a txt as a string from web. But my txt come like this: "0.222 L/H" and i want to use only the number "0.222".

How can i do that?

```
String textFileUrl = "http://projecthflow.hol.es/consumo.php";
        String textFileText = "";

        Request httpRequest = new Request();
        httpRequest.execute(textFileUrl);
        try {
            textFileText = httpRequest.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("The online text file contains: " + textFileText);


        TextView textViewcons = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textConsumo);
        textViewcons.setText(textFileText);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the " L/H" by an empty string if this is the exact suffix you have:

```
textFileText = textFileText.replace(" L\/H", "");
textViewcons.setText(textFileText);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a simple string split or substring

```
String[] temp = textFileText.split(" "); //splits up the string using the whitespace as the delimiter
String numberText = temp[0]; //the 0.222 is in the first array element

textViewcons.setText(numberText);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below have more flexible way to get only number (and number with decimal)

```
textFileText = textFileText.replaceAll("[^0-9?!\\.]","")
```

For example if you have `0.222L/H`, `0.222 L/H` or `0.222 K/H`, it still can get correct number value `0.222`